# R spaghetti plot - changing line colour with connected points

Tags: r

Spaghetti plot with geom_line and geom_smooth.
I have to plot "`f0`" according to "`time_steps`" with the lines changing their colour according to the factor "`part`" without disconnecting between its two levels "`os`" and "`fv`". Also the smooth disappear when "`part`" changes.

The structure of my dataset:

```
structure(list(time_steps = 1:20, f0.2 = c(203.61, 204.62, 204.23, 
207.71, 198.5, 184.43, 185.15, 182.13, 183.2, 189.47, 188.88, 
188.43, 188.53, 189.41, 191.15, 193.76, 196.6, 199.44, 201.45, 
202.53), part = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("os", 
"fv"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I wrote:

```
ggplot (df, aes(time_steps, f0, colour = (part))) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) + geom_smooth(size = 2)
```

The plot I got with a disconnected line:

[image: here]

Does someone have suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you use `dput(your_data)` and paste that into your question? `str()` does not give reproducible data to use.

Comment: Also, breaking the line plot by color will always leave a gap unless there is a point in common between the two values of `part`. That gap signifies that there is no value of `time_steps  > 10` for `part == "os"` and no values of `time_steps < 12` for `part == "fv"`.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the line plot by color will always leave a gap unless there is a point in common between the two values of part. That gap signifies that there is no value of `time_steps  > 10` for `part == "os"` and no values of `time_steps < 12` for `part == "fv"`.

Using some simulated data that looks like yours, here is a work around. It involves using `geom_line` twice, once without a color aesthetic mapped so you can connect the points. Then I used `stat_smooth()` twice (once for the line and once for the ribbon) because it gives more control over the appearance of the plot.

```
df <- data.frame(time_steps = 1:20,
                 f0 = round(runif(20, 190, 210)),
                 part = c(rep("os", 10), rep("fv", 10)))

ggplot(df) +
   geom_line(aes(x = time_steps, y = f0), color = "black", size = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) +
   geom_line(aes(x = time_steps, y = f0, color = part), size = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
   stat_smooth(geom ='line', aes(x = time_steps, y = f0), color = "black", size = 1.5, linetype = 2, alpha=0.5) + 
   stat_smooth(geom = 'ribbon', aes(x = time_steps, y = f0), color = "NA", fill = "black", alpha = 0.1)
```

[image: trying to plot what the OP wants]

Comment: Hi thank you very much! Here is the data frame:                                     structure(list(time_steps = 1:20, f0.2 = c(203.61, 204.62, 204.23, 
207.71, 198.5, 184.43, 185.15, 182.13, 183.2, 189.47, 188.88, 
188.43, 188.53, 189.41, 191.15, 193.76, 196.6, 199.44, 201.45, 
202.53), part = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("os", 
"fv"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Actually there is the "11" value for time_steps between 10 and 12 (the first value which shifts to "fv", so from 1 to 10 is "os" and from 11 to 20 is "fv"). Moreover, I would need the resulting line to be smoothed and look like a curve, as in the image I attached to the post. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot